# Python list-of-list idioms

Tags: python

data2['C'] is a list that looks like:

```
[['20120524', '26.31'], ['20120523', '26.08'], ['20120522', '26.52'], ['20120521', '25.75']]
```

I want to write code that can iterate across d['C'][i][0] and find the list index corresponding to a specific value (a date stored as YYYYMMDD). I still find Python's for loop idioms confusing, and would like clarification on why the first block of code is invalid but the second block of code is valid. Also, if there is a built-in Python function that will do the search procedure I described, please share.

Doesn't work:

```
>>> print data2['C'][i][0] for i in range(len(data2['C']))
 File "<stdin>", line 1
   print data2['C'][i][0] for i in range(len(data2['C']))
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Works:

```
>>> for i in range(len(data2['C'])):
...     print data2['C'][i][0]
... 
20120524
20120523
20120522
20120521
```

Comment: "If there is a built-in Python function that will..." How about this: `for s in data2['C']: print s[0]`? If you need `i` for later: `for i, s in enumerate(data2['C']): print i, s[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` can be used in two ways: in an explicit `for` loop (like your second code block) or in a list/dict/generator comprehension [(docs)](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
print [data2['C'][i][0] for i in range(len(data2['C']))]
```

Note the brackets. `[]` means list, `{}` - a dict and `()` with `for` inside - a generator expression.

To have the output identical to the second one, do

```
print '\n'.join([str(data2['C'][i][0]) for i in range(len(data2['C']))])
```

or even

```
print '\n'.join(str(data2['C'][i][0]) for i in range(len(data2['C'])))
```

This will be a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first code is a bad [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) but the second is a bad iterator. The [for](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) in python is a iterator, so, you can do this:

```
for i in data2['C']:
    print i[0]
```

or

```
dates = [i[0] for i in data2['C']]
print dates
```

Comment: This will not work at all. range() returns a list of integers from 0 to len(X)-1 (including the borders). i[0] doesn't make sense in that context.